# JQuery DateTimePicker not working in InternetExplorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I have a datepicker that works fine in Firefox but not in Internet Explorer(9). Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

```
<head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src='<spring:theme code="jquery.timepicker"/>'</script>
</head>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#globalSearchStartDate').datetimepicker({
            inline: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the field:

```
<td width=220 nowrap="nowrap"> Date From:&nbsp;<form:input path="globalSearchStartDate"/></td>
```

When the page loads nothing works - no other functions ever get called. If I try in Firefox it works fine or if I comment the function above out then everything else works fine. Can someone please tell me what the issue is here?!

Comment: `src='<spring:theme code="jquery.timepicker"/>'`  -- Can you spot the problem?

Comment: @Ahren I did think this but why does it work fine in Firefox? What should it be?

Comment: Sorry, the above snippet was too short to actually highlight the problem... `src='<spring:theme code="jquery.timepicker"/>'</script>`

Comment: @Ahren - as i said before what should it be? I tried changing to jquery.datetimepicker but it throws a 500 server error...

Comment: Chrome and Firefox DOM parser are quite intelligent. They try and fix some errors in the source code. This is sometimes not good for developers. If they don't do cross-browser testing this error will go to production servers. And for IE, well what can I say?

Answer (score 1):

Hey there is `'>'` missing in the script tag in your head section.
Apart from IE all the browser are intelligent. but IE has always been headache for the developer.

Comment: I tried with the missing tag and its still got the same problem in IE. Any other ideas?